# wampserver drupal phpinfo always showing

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, wampserver

I've installed wampserver on my Windows VM machine and I have set up a copy of my Drupal web site included the .htaccess file.

The site appears to work fine but on every page I seem to have phpInfo() include which means I need to scroll a long way down to see the content.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd do a global search through your source code looking for the lingering phpinfo() call.

Comment: It's fine on live - now unless it has been set up so that phpInfo() does not get displayed - I'll check

Comment: Found 0 occurrences in 5080 files.  It's a strange one as when I googled this, nothing came up.  So must be something extremely stupid.  I'll set up another site.

Comment: I can't believe I was so stupid - in searching for it as well I did not spell it properly.  You are absolutely right, see my answer to my question.

Comment: It happens to the best of us

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can't believe how incredibly stupid I have been.  I remembered that I had put phpinfo(); in my index.php when I wanted to test for it being installed.  And then I forgot to take it out, and it meant it was included on each page.